# Avoid user interaction when we use CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, jailbreak, ios6.0

Is it possible on a jailbreak iPhone get gps location without user interaction?

In my code

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]
```

always return `kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted`.

If I use

```
[CLLocationManager setDefaultEffectiveBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class]]; // privat api
```

I getting `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`.

Comment: Have you try using simple MKMapView?

Comment: How? I try get gps position in background

Comment: alloc n init mkmapview , then set `yes` to showuserlocation n then use `mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude`

Comment: My program  work in background, program has not a GUI. Then I call `[[MKMapView alloc] init];` I getting `Trace/BPT trap: 5`